# Permission Denied (publickey) gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to push my locally created gitrepo to gitlab first time  at that time I execute this command for pushing files.

```
git push --set-upstream git@gitlab.com:user_name/work.git master
```

and I am facing below error.

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

Comment: See https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: @ElpieKay I already created and added key in my gitlab account

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: okay thanks let me check

Comment: hey I am stuck in gitlab not in github

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add private key identities to the authentication agent?

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Answer (score 0):

First generate pair of ssh-key on your local git bash

Open Git bash Terminal and type this

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "youremailaddress"
```

Then press enter and enter

then do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

and copy the contents of the id_rsa.pub file to your clipboard and go to your gitlab profile `settings >> ssh key` and paste this key and done